# Multiplying two matricies not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to rotate a point in 3d. I have the code working for rotating it in all 3 x,y,z axis by doing 3 matrix multiplications. Then realized I don't need x axis for my case. So I ended up with this

```
function rotate(p, xr, yr, zr) {
    var si_x = Math.sin(xr);
    var co_x = Math.cos(xr);
    var si_y = Math.sin(yr);
    var co_y = Math.cos(yr);
    var si_z = Math.sin(zr);
    var co_z = Math.cos(zr);
    var xrm = [
        [1,0,0],
        [0,co_x,-si_x],
        [0, si_x,co_x]
    ];
    var yrm = [
        [co_y,0,si_y],
        [0,1,0],
        [-si_y, 0, co_y]
    ];
    var zrm = [
        [co_z,-si_z,0],
        [si_z, co_z, 0],
        [0,0,1]
    ];
    //p = matrixMultiply(xrm, p);
    p = matrixMultiply(yrm, p);
    p = matrixMultiply(zrm, p);
    return p;
}
```

This seems to work fine. But then realized, I am basically doing

```
p' = Yp
p' = Zp'
```

when I can just do

```
p' = (ZY)p
```

But when I implement it, it warps the results for some y values, where the same input angles worked in the code above.

```
function rotate(p, xr, yr, zr) {
    var si_y = Math.sin(yr);
    var co_y = Math.cos(yr);
    var si_z = Math.sin(zr);
    var co_z = Math.cos(zr);
    var rr = [
        [co_z*si_y,-si_z,si_y*co_z],
        [si_z*co_y, co_z, si_z*si_y],
        [-si_y,0,co_y]
    ];
    p = matrixMultiply(rr, p);
    return p;
}
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Thanks

Comment: your ZY *(`rr`)* ain't correct, it's way to short for the result of multiplying two matrices.

Comment: I tried doing ZY again but came out with the same result.

Comment: figured it out, row 1 column 1 should be `co_z*co_y`.

Comment: right, sry, my bad. didn't realize all the `0` values when scanning over the code, only after writing the full matrix multiplication down.

Comment: @omega—if the cause was a simple typo or similar, close the question.